# Will unsuccessful call alter by-reference passed result?

Tags: c++, cgal

Not sure if this question is plain C++ or library specific.
I want to know, if functions, that return success code and output their result to a passed reference alter output reference in case of failure?

The library used is CGAL

```
using namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;
Mesh out;
bool valid_union = PMP::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1, mesh2, out);
```

Comment: What does the documentation for `corefine_and_compute_union` tell you?

Comment: Have you tried to find the answer in the library documentation? Otherwise, this question should be better asked on the library support pages.

Comment: I feel this is library specific. Why the answerer provides that C++ won't alter the references, some libraries will set values to 0 (or whatever) if the call fails so you don't try to use the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about returning a true or false value from a function; i.e. whether your function returns success or failure has no meaning whether it changed the arguments:

```
bool do_something(int& a, int& b) {
    a += ++b;
    return false;
}
```

still changes `a` and `b`, no matter whether you `return false` or `return true`.

It's hence a thing that the author of that function decided when they wrote that function. I hope they documented what they do!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is just I wanted to know. So there is no convention or language constrains (in my opinion it was not, but just in case) for not to ruin outs.